# how i can control in area of Contours in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

**hi i am struggling with this code here**

**my quesions is -->>> how can i control the area inside the Contours .. for instance i want to blur or draw a line in this box**

*i am reading from a video here*

[image: this is the box i want to control to for instance draw line inside him]

```
    while True:
    ret, frames = cap.read()
    if frames is None:
        break
    frames = imutils.resize(frames, width=600)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)

    # find contours in the thresholded image and initialize the
    # shape detector
    (new, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:30]

    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:  # Select the contour with 4 corners
            NumberPlateCnt = approx  # This is our approx Number Plate Contour
            cv2.GaussianBlur(NumberPlateCnt, (43, 43), 30) # here when i blured

            break
    cv2.drawContours(frames, [NumberPlateCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Final frames With Number Plate Detected", frames)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # cv2.imshow("Final frames With Number Plate Detect", cnts)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
```

**here when i blured .. what should i replace ??..**

```
          if len(approx) == 4:  # Select the contour with 4 corners
            NumberPlateCnt = approx  # This is our approx Number Plate Contour
            cv2.GaussianBlur(NumberPlateCnt, (43, 43), 30)

            break
```

Comment: Two ways you can do this:
1) create a method to draw the contours, whereas inside of the countours you change the pixels
2) draw contours; find all pixels inside them, blur each one

Comment: Do you asking about bluring or about cropping the image?

Comment: @Meisam i am asking about bluring inside the green box

Comment: So you want the inside the box blurred and the outside unblurred?

Comment: @Meisam that exactly what i want

Comment: You just need top-left and bottom-right corner coordinates from the contour, then `frames[x0:x1, y0:y1] = cv2.GaussianBlur(frames[x0:x1,y0:y1] , (43,43), 30)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have the original image so so I explain :

Make a black `image` with the same size as `frames` and change the drawcontour like this:

```
cv2.drawContours(image, [NumberPlateCnt], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1) # I changed 3 to -1
```

This will gives you a binary mask which only has the plate area. Inverse this mask (`255-image`) and name that as `image2`.

Now multiply first mask (`image`) to `frames` and do the blurring on the result.
Then multiply second mask (`image2`) to `frames` and add the result with the last blurred image. Here is the pseudo code:

```
final_image = blur((image/255.)*frames) + ((image2/255.)*frames)
```

That's it.

Comment: thanks man ...that's work for me ..but i just drop (255- image ) because it effect on my whole video ..because when i show the image2 it's just a white image ...that's right?? ..or  does not suppose to be white ???.....

Comment: @AhmadOmar You're right, the concept was true but I had a little mistake in the code. I modified that.